# Champernowne-like squares, are there any?

Tags: number-theory

I read about the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant) on Wikipedia a couple of days ago, and I got curious about something similar: is there some "Champernowne-like" number; that is, a concatenation of all numbers up to some $n \ge 2$ (like $1234567891011$), that is a perfect square? I've done a computer search up to $n=2000$, but I haven't found any.

Are there any? If not, how may we prove this? Any thoughts on this are welcome!

Comment: [This](http://oeis.org/A007908) says that the proper name for your sequence is the "Smarandache consecutive sequence". See [Smarandache's book](http://fs.gallup.unm.edu//OPNS.pdf) for instance.

Comment: None to $10^4.$ It should be possible to test this more efficiently than testing individual members (find the first digits of a square root, then square and see if the result is close to an integer) but I haven't attempted anything along those lines.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: @J.M.: I'm pretty sure Smarandache was not the first to study this sequence!

Comment: @Charles: I'm sure you're right, but it was his name that got used... :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any perfect square in the sequence $12,123,1234,12345,...$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1902575/is-there-any-perfect-square-in-the-sequence-12-123-1234-12345)