# Perfect square in the sequence formed by consecutive numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, decimal-expansion

I recently saw a question [Is there any perfect square in the sequence $12,123,1234,12345,...$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1902575/769348)

This led to thinking about a new question.

---

Consider [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A057137) that is the sequence formed by concatenating next digit at right-hand end (where the next digit after 9 is again 0).

ie
$1,
12,
123,
1234,
12345,
123456,
1234567,
…
123456789012
…$

Is there any perfect square in the sequence?

Answer (score 3):

NO

---

Computational check for numbers mod powers of 10.

1. Mod 10: ∈{0,1,4,5,6,9} perfect squares can end only with these digits
2. Mod 100: ∈{01, 56, 89} They are the only pairs with consecutive numbers
3. Mod 1000: ∈{456} Using computation, 901 and 789 are eliminated. No perfect square can end with 789 or 901.
4. Mod 10000: ∈{3456}, Mod 100000:  ∈{23456}  and so on continues

Let us assume that the number is
(1234567890)..k..123456

Test of divisibility by 3:
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0 = 45
1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21
The sum of all digits of a number is 45*k+21 which is divisible by 3

Test of divisibility by 9:
45*k+21 can never be divisible by 9

A perfect square divisible by 3 but not divisible by 9 cannot exist.